# systemVeilog - pass array of unknown size

Tags: function, system-verilog, dynamic-arrays

I have the following function:

```
   function void foo_arr_bit (int seed, ref bit [*] mem, string  mem_name);
      for (int i=0; i< mem.size(); i++)
    mem[i] = my_randomize_int(seed, mem[i], mem_name);     
   endfunction: foo_arr_bit
```

I call the function by:

```
 foo_arr_bit(seed, data_bit, "data_bit");
```

Where data_bit can be:
bit [1:0]/ bit [2:0]/ bit [3:0]/ bit [4:0]/ bit [5:0] etc...

When I try to compile I got the following error:
 near "[*": syntax error, unexpected [* , expecting IDENTIFIER or TYPE_IDENTIFIER or NETTYPE_IDENTIFIER.

Answer (score 1):

`[*]` is not the correct syntax for a dynamic array, use `[]`.

Your array can only be dynamic in the *unpacked* dimension. So you cannot have `bit [] mem_array`, but must have `bit mem_array[]`.

Finally a function using pass by reference cannot have a static lifetime. That is, it must be declared as *automatic*.

```
function automatic void foo_arr_bit (int seed, ref bit mem[], string  mem_name);
  for (int i=0; i< mem.size(); i++)
    mem[i] = my_randomize_int(seed, mem[i], mem_name);     
endfunction: foo_arr_bit
```

Edit: But even with these changes you face a bigger issue. Passing by reference demands very strict typing. There is no casting allowed so I expect there to be issues with type conversion.

Furthermore, passing by reference is not really necessary in your case. Use `inout` instead.

```
function automatic void foo_arr_bit (input int seed, string  mem_name, inout bit mem[]);
  for (int i=0; i< mem.size(); i++)
    mem[i] = my_randomize_int(seed, mem[i], mem_name);
endfunction: foo_arr_bit
```

Comment: my input is packed array, not unpaked.

Comment: Systemverilog does not have dynamic packed arrays. Using a parameterizable class to encapsule your function could be a solution. More on that here: http://forums.accellera.org/topic/1177-how-to-pass-variable-sized-packed-arguments-to-a-taskfunction/

Or just pass SIZE to the function and have a sufficiently large packed array.